# How do I ensure my product is correct the first time?

Tags: security, formal-methods, system-reliability

I am working on a product that will not be able to be updated once released.  Furthermore, if the product malfunctions, the results may include death, serious bodily harm, or major financial setbacks.  Therefore, my code *must* be correct the first time, as I will not get a second chance.

What techniques are available for this?  I already plan on extensive testing, but I know that testing can only demonstrate the presence of bugs, not prove their absence.

Comment: The most reliable technique is to refuse to work given these requirements. I've successfully written life critical software (so far) and I refuse to work for anyone that refuses to acknowledge the risks. If we can update space probes we can update whatever your fixing to kill people with. You have an obligation to say "no!" when the boss needlessly puts people at risk.

Comment: @candied_orange That is true.  That said, in life-critical software, there is a chance that a bug could first manifest as someone dying.

Comment: This question is way-too-broad for the format of this site. There were lots of books written about creating almost bug-free software and high-reliable systems. "Formal verification" is just one of many techniques, definitely not "the" solution. The most important keywords here are "risk analysis" and "redundancy".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is actually to hire software developers who have been doing that kind of work before, and to prepare for an enormous bill. If you are asking for help here, then frankly you don’t have a chance.

Comment: I agree, with the caveat that someone had to be the first.

Comment: @Demi, someone may have had to be the first, but they probably weren't "correct first time".

Comment: @Demi I think the penalties are lower for people who are first. If someone dies for an unforeseeable reason, it's a tragic accident. But as humanity gets more practice with this sort of thing (say, space rockets) the amount of things that are unforeseeable goes down. Even if you couldn't foresee the problems with a 100% oxygen atmosphere, someone who's built a bunch of rockets before you could have.

Comment: @immibis True.  Which is why the Mercury, Gemini, and Apollo astronauts were test pilots.  Humanity accepts risks where there is no alternative, but not when they could have been avoided.

Answer (score -4):

The solution is formal verification.  This involves writing not only the software, but also a formal specification.  Most importantly, one then writes a machine-checked proof that the program one has written is correct against the specification.

Formal verification is difficult and expensive.  However, it can be justified in extremely critical code, and code that could kill someone if it breaks certainly qualifies.

Comment: Formal verification can only show that a program confirms to the spec, but that does neither proof the spec contains no bugs, nor does it proof the system as a whole (including its hardware, operating system, environment) will work flawlessly. Which means formal verification, though surely a strong tool, needs still to be accompanied by extensive testing.

Comment: @DocBrown That is correct.

Comment: It's a little pretentious to ask an open-ended question then answer it yourself with "The solution is …". That really doesn't sound like you're actually looking for feedback. If you want feedback you could try working this answer into your question as something you've tried but rejected because of the cost.

Comment: @DocBrown: On the other hand, tests can only show the presence of bugs, not their absence. Furthermore, tests only consider samples from the input space whereas formal verification can also consider assertions that are universally quantified. Of course, I agree that it is better to have a combination of the two.